# Python selenium Webdriver Chrome fix

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The code:

```
from selenium import  webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/derlinuxnutzer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

The error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/derlinuxnutzer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/hh.py", line 2, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/derlinuxnutzer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/chromedriver')
File "/home/derlinuxnutzer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in **init**
RemoteWebDriver.**init**(
File "/home/derlinuxnutzer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in **init**
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/home/derlinuxnutzer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "/home/derlinuxnutzer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/derlinuxnutzer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

It should be with extension `chromedriver.exe`

```py
from selenium import webdriver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/derlinuxnutzer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Ensure that your path is correct by calling it from terminal using `cd` command